# Swift typecast from AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I'm trying to fetch data from my store but get the following error:

`'Event' is not identical to 'AnyObject'`

I've got a `events` variable, which is an `Event` array. I guess that the data coming back from the fetch request is from type `AnyObject`. So I try to typecast it to `[Event]` but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
var events: [Event] = []

func loadDataFromDB() {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
  events = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Event]
}
```

Comment: Try to use context! instead of context?

Comment: No that didn't help, I've tried before, but thaks for the suggestion.

Comment: Update: possibly it worked, the error took like 10 min to get away on its own. I'll give an update if it really worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like some kind of bug when optional chaining is involved. Use these alternatives to workaround:

```
events = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [AnyObject]? as [Event]
events = (context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil))! as [Event]
events = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Event]
```

To be safe I would recommend using:

```
if let result = context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) {
    events = result as [Event]
}
```

As `executeFetchRequest` returns `nil` if there was and error.

Comment: it's not a bug. `executeFetchRequest()` returns `[AnyObject]?` -- an optional

Comment: Not that, but the fact that you can cast `context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [AnyObject]? as [Event]`, but cannot cast `context?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Event]`